# how to pass session in controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, controller

I have a problem about session in CodeIgniter.
I initialize a session in Login/submit 
Then , i have to check in another controller if the user is logged.
So i would use:

```
if ( $this->session->userdata('login_state') == FALSE ) {
      $this->load->view('header');    // no session established, kick back to login page
     }
```

The problem is that in the controller in which i would check the login_state , i can't use the `$this->session` variable.
If i load the session library in this controller , i'll initialize a new session and the `$this->session->userdata('login_state')` will be always false.
I tried the :

```
   $ci = & get_instance();
   $ci->session->userdata('login_state');
```

but it doesn't work.I don't know why..
I would not create a class to share the session variable. is there a clear way to pass the session variable through controllers?

Login controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {
  public function submit() {
            $this->load->library('session');
    // Prendo i dati passati dal form
      $username = $this->input->post('username');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');

    // read user's credentials from db, through Login Model
      if ( $username == "my_username"  && $password == "my_password" )  {
        $this->session->set_userdata('login_state', TRUE);
      } 
      else {
        redirect( '/' );    // redirect back to login page
      }
  }
```

ragazze controller

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ragazze extends CI_Controller {    
    public function search()
    {   

    if ( $this->session->userdata('login_state') == FALSE ) {
      $this->load->view('header');    // no session established, kick back to login page
     }
     else{
        $this->load->model('ragazza_model');
        #Prelevo il valore passato tramite post
        $nome_ragazza=$this->input->post('nome');
        if ($nome_ragazza) {
        $nome_ragazza = $this->ragazza_model->get_girl_by_name($nome_ragazza);
        }
        $data['nome_ragazza'] =$nome_ragazza;
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('ragazza_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'Nome', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        //Questo viene eseguito anche quando il form
        //non `e compilato, cio´e la prima volta che si  -
        //la pagina con il form html
          $this->load->view('header');
          $this->load->view('menu');
          $this->load->view('ragazze/search',$data);
          $this->load->view('footer');
        }
        else{
        //Se i controlli sono positivi, redireziono l' -
          $this->load->view('header');
          $this->load->view('menu');
          $this->load->view('ragazze/search',$data);
          $this->load->view('footer');
        }
       }
       }
```

config.php

```
 $config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

EDIT: ok i discovered somethin interesting. If i use Explorer..everythings works..So the problem is Firefox..i don't know Why. Can you help?

EDIT:  I tried a lot of things.. but at the end mybe it was a cookie problem of my firefox. I deleted oll my cookies and now the session seems to work. Really , i don't know if the problem was this. I changed also somethings in the config but before to delete my cookies it didin't work. So guys , if you have my same problem with Firefox ( cause in Explorer the session, so the same code,  worked) try just to delete your cookies. If someone has an answer to this strange thing, i'll appreciate it.

Comment: what version of CI are you using?

Comment: in your `config.php`, can you provide how your session configuration is set?

Comment: can you show the code thats initializing the session in `Login/submit` ?

Comment: sure. Read the first post  :)

Comment: that is not initializing your session. Show the code where you are setting the userdata using `set_userdata`

Comment: it' s in the login controller. i posted it. However, here:   if ( $username == "my_username"  && $password == "my_password" )  {
        $this->session->set_userdata('login_state', TRUE);
      } 
      else {
        redirect( '/' );    // redirect back to login page
      }

Comment: i added the config file

Comment: version CI 2.0 correct?

Comment: in method `search()` you are not loading the session library: `$this->load->library('session');` have you tried that?

Comment: if it does work, but your sessions are just renewing themselves, then I believe the session is renewing itself because of this setting: `['sess_time_to_update'] = 300`; or "renew every 5 minutes". Ideally you want to autoload your session library if you will use it across your app.

Comment: if i load the library i will add new row to the session table every time i reload the page...and it's not good cause if i set_userdata to a session , i ll' use a new one on the reloading.

Comment: I tried it locally, and it works fine.. perhaps try it on a clean install of CI to see if it works. There might be some problems with current installation you are using

Comment: it's really strange. can you send me your codeigniter files?

Comment: sure where should i send it to?

Comment: plusgarbage@gmail.com

Comment: sent. check it out.let me know how it works

Comment: i red it.. man, i can't understand..it's how i made it. Why if i reload the page i'll see new session row in my db?

Comment: so the problem still happens when you run my code?

Comment: i didn't run your code. I only see the code. I'm uploading in my server.

Comment: i have the same problem even with your code. I'm using Altervista.org as free hosting.. And firefox

Comment: well cant say i didnt try.. I dont know what the problem could be. hopefully somebody here will be able to find an answer for you. good luck.

Comment: ok i discovered somethin interesting. If i use Explorer..everythings works..So the problem is Firefox..i don't know Why

Answer (score 0):

In your autoload.php config file, auto load the session like this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Now you don't load it again, and you don't "pass" session variables. They are simply available for use everywhere.

Comment: i tried but this doesn't work. It's the same to load session library in every controller. Every time i visit a page , a new session is created on my DB. This is not good.However , i edited my post with the controller